# Unable to delete All Contacts in Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud

I have started the contact deletion process in Marketing Cloud. I have selected to delete contacts using Data Extension in Contact Builder.It is showing pending deletion from the past 15 hours.Is this a permission issue or is anything else changed. I have successfully done this process multiple times in the past .

Answer (score 0):

[Check to make sure your suppression period is not set to the default of 14 days](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_cab_enable_contact_delete.htm&type=5).

If it's set to delete immediately, then something else might be preventing the deletion from occurring, because 14 hours sounds like too long to wait for an instant deletion. Support might be able to clear the request and provide some insight if it's an actual bug.